# Resizing button, adding button on FormLayout using loop and removing FormLayout border

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Here is **MCVE ( A Minimal, Complete, verifiable example )** should run right off the bat

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFormLayout, QGroupBox,QPushButton, QScrollArea


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('MCVE')

        '''Window Background'''
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.black)
        self.setPalette(p)

        '''Core Layouts'''
        self.mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.picLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.redditSubs = QVBoxLayout()
        self.downloadBar = QHBoxLayout()
        self.panel = QWidget()
        self.profileInfo = QGridLayout()

        '''redditSubs Layout -----------------------------------------------------'''
        self.formLayout = QFormLayout()
        self.groupBox = QGroupBox()
        labelList = []
        favList = []
        favIcon = QPushButton('Favs')
        favIcon.setToolTip('<i><b>Add to favourites</i></b>')
        subscribedList = ['AccidentalRenaissance', 'HadToHurt', 'WidescreenWallpaper', 'iamverybadass',
                          'LivestreamFail', 'CatastrophicFailure', 'KidsAreFuckingStupid', 'therewasanattempt',
                          'BetterEveryLoop', 'madlads', 'IdiotsInCars', 'youseeingthisshit', 'blackmagicfuckery',
                          'WatchPeopleDieInside', 'SequelMemes', 'iamatotalpieceofshit', 'cleavesdropping',
                          'PewdiepieSubmissions', 'technicallythetruth', 'KeanuBeingAwesome', 'science', 'TikTokCringe',
                          'Cringetopia']
        for i in range(len(subscribedList)):
            labelList.append(QLabel('r/' + subscribedList[i]))
            favList.append(favIcon)
            self.formLayout.addRow(labelList[i], favList[i])
        self.groupBox.setLayout(self.formLayout)
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scroll.setWidget(self.groupBox)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.redditSubs.addWidget(scroll)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName('backgroundColor')
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: #707070; font-size: 20px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 15px;}'
                                    'QGroupBox#backgroundColor {background-color: rgb(20, 21, 24); border: 1px solid black}'
                                    'QPushButton {text-align:center; font-size: 20px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 15px;}')

        '''------------------------------------------------------'''

        '''Nested Layout'''
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.profileInfo, 0, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.picLayout, 0, 1)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.redditSubs, 1, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.downloadBar, 1, 1)

        '''Widgets'''
        self.display = QLabel('QHBoxLayout()')
        self.download = QLabel('QHBoxLayout()')
        self.subs = QLabel('QVBoxLayout()')
        self.fileInfo = QLabel('QGridLayout()')

        '''AddWidgets'''
        self.picLayout.addWidget(self.display)
        self.downloadBar.addWidget(self.download)
        self.redditSubs.addWidget(self.subs)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.panel, 0, 0)
        self.profileInfo.addWidget(self.fileInfo, 0, 0)

        '''Stylesheet'''
        self.panel.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        self.display.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: white;}')
        self.download.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: white;}')
        '''Initiating  mainLayout '''
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.showMaximized()
    app.exec_()
```

**Issues:**

1. Labels are getting added one after the other but not the buttons. I did `favList.append(QPushButton('Favs'))` which works fine but this way I cannot add icons.
2. Unable to resize buttons
3. Can't seem to remove the border around the formLayout.

Added : BEFORE/AFTER PIC

[image]

**Added code:**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QScrollArea


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("MCVE")

        """Window Background"""
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.darkYellow)
        self.setPalette(p)

        """Core Layouts"""
        self.mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.picLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.redditSubs = QVBoxLayout()
        self.downloadBar = QHBoxLayout()
        self.profileInfo = QGridLayout()

        """Nested Layout"""
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.profileInfo, 0, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.picLayout, 0, 1)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.redditSubs, 1, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.downloadBar, 1, 1)

        """Widgets"""
        self.display = QLabel("QHBoxLayout()")
        self.download = QLabel("QHBoxLayout()")
        self.subs = QLabel("QVBoxLayout()")
        self.fileInfo = QLabel("QGridLayout()")
        self.panel = QWidget()
        self.redditWidget = QWidget()

        '''redditSubs Layout -----------------------------------------------------'''

        lay1 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.redditWidget.setLayout(lay1)

        subscribedList = ['AccidentalRenaissance', 'HadToHurt', 'WidescreenWallpaper', 'iamverybadass',
                          'LivestreamFail', 'CatastrophicFailure', 'KidsAreFuckingStupid', 'therewasanattempt',
                          'BetterEveryLoop', 'madlads', 'IdiotsInCars', 'youseeingthisshit', 'blackmagicfuckery',
                          'WatchPeopleDieInside', 'SequelMemes', 'iamatotalpieceofshit', 'cleavesdropping',
                          'PewdiepieSubmissions', 'technicallythetruth', 'KeanuBeingAwesome', 'science', 'TikTokCringe',
                          'Cringetopia']



        for i in range(len(subscribedList)):
            lay1.addWidget(QLabel('/r' + subscribedList[i]))
            favIcon = QPushButton('Favs')
            favIcon.setFixedSize(40, 40)
            lay1.addWidget(favIcon, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setWidget(self.redditWidget)
        lay1.addWidget(scroll) ##
        self.redditWidget.setObjectName('backgroundColor')
        self.redditWidget.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: #707070; font-size: 15px;}'
                                        'QWidget#backgroundColor {background-color: rgb(20, 21, 24)};'
                                        'QPushButton {text-align:center; font-size: 15px;}')

        self.redditSubs.addWidget(self.redditWidget)

        '''------------------------------------------------------'''

        """AddWidgets"""

        self.picLayout.addWidget(self.display)
        self.downloadBar.addWidget(self.download)
        self.profileInfo.addWidget(self.panel)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.panel)
        lay.addWidget(self.fileInfo)

        """Stylesheet"""
        self.panel.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")

        """Initiating  mainLayout """
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.showMaximized()
    app.exec_()
```

Buttons are not on the same level as Labels, and Scroll bar isn't working and showing up. '##' when commented only then it runs.

Comment: As I pointed out in a previous comment in the questions related to design, it is better to place an image of what you have now and another of what you want to get to understand you better.

Comment: **ADDED**. Will keep that in mind while posting from next time onward.

Comment: An improvement is that you place the 2 images separately so that the details are better seen.

Comment: If you don't want a border around the form layout then why are you using a QGroupBox instead of a QWidget?

Comment: Also you need to create a separate button for each row. At the moment you are adding the same button over and over again, which is consequently removed from the previous row every time you add it to a new row.

Comment: I tried using QWidget but failed, after googling I found what I wanted but using QGroupBox. So copied it and started tinkering to meet my needs. Had help from @eyllanesc in a previous post which tackled an issue which I was facing while implementing QWidget earlier. Will give it another go tomorrow. Thanks for that insight, Heike.

Comment: @Heike I tried doing as you suggested, been able to add buttons, resize, align but QScrollArea isn't working for some reason. Can you please have a look ? Code **ADDED**. Thank you :)

Comment: `self.redditWidget` should be inside the scroll area, not the other way around. You should remove the line  `lay1.addWidget(scroll)`, and add `scroll` to `self.redditSubs` instead of `self.redditWidget`, i.e. use `self.redditSubs.addWidget(scroll)` instead of `self.redditSubs.addWidget(self.redditWidget)`

Comment: @Heike **WORKED** Now that I read it, it makes sense ! Thanks. BTW, Since, my layout is VBox, buttons and labels are not coming within a row. In first row, label and the corresponding button on row 2. How to solve this ? Back then, with formlayout it was just addRow.

Comment: Just had to change from lay1 to QVBoxLayout to QGridLayout and giving positions of i,0 and i,1 to labels and buttons respectively. **SOLVED**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QScrollArea


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("MCVE")

        """Window Background"""
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.darkYellow)
        self.setPalette(p)

        """Core Layouts"""
        self.mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.picLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.redditSubs = QVBoxLayout()
        self.downloadBar = QHBoxLayout()
        self.profileInfo = QGridLayout()

        """Nested Layout"""
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.profileInfo, 0, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.picLayout, 0, 1)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.redditSubs, 1, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.downloadBar, 1, 1)

        """Widgets"""
        self.display = QLabel("QHBoxLayout()")
        self.download = QLabel("QHBoxLayout()")
        self.subs = QLabel("QVBoxLayout()")
        self.fileInfo = QLabel("QGridLayout()")
        self.panel = QWidget()
        self.redditWidget = QWidget()

        '''redditSubs Layout -----------------------------------------------------'''

        lay1 = QGridLayout()
        self.redditWidget.setLayout(lay1)

        subscribedList = ['AccidentalRenaissance', 'HadToHurt', 'WidescreenWallpaper', 'iamverybadass',
                          'LivestreamFail', 'CatastrophicFailure', 'KidsAreFuckingStupid', 'therewasanattempt',
                          'BetterEveryLoop', 'madlads', 'IdiotsInCars', 'youseeingthisshit', 'blackmagicfuckery',
                          'WatchPeopleDieInside', 'SequelMemes', 'iamatotalpieceofshit', 'cleavesdropping',
                          'PewdiepieSubmissions', 'technicallythetruth', 'KeanuBeingAwesome', 'science', 'TikTokCringe',
                          'Cringetopia']



        for i in range(len(subscribedList)):
            lay1.addWidget(QLabel('/r' + subscribedList[i]),i,0)
            favIcon = QPushButton('Favs')
            favIcon.setFixedSize(40, 40)
            lay1.addWidget(favIcon, i,1)
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setWidget(self.redditWidget)
        # lay1.addWidget(scroll)
        self.redditWidget.setObjectName('backgroundColor')
        self.redditWidget.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: #707070; font-size: 15px;}'
                                        'QWidget#backgroundColor {background-color: rgb(20, 21, 24)};'
                                        'QPushButton {text-align:center; font-size: 15px;}')

        self.redditSubs.addWidget(scroll)

        '''------------------------------------------------------'''

        """AddWidgets"""

        self.picLayout.addWidget(self.display)
        self.downloadBar.addWidget(self.download)
        self.profileInfo.addWidget(self.panel)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.panel)
        lay.addWidget(self.fileInfo)

        """Stylesheet"""
        self.panel.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")

        """Initiating  mainLayout """
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.showMaximized()
    app.exec_()
```

Just the way I wanted.